# Incrementing Timer - don't know how to pause and continue

Tags: android, timer, android-runonuithread

I have an Android activity where I want a timer to start when it's open, but when you click the screen I want the pause symbol to show and the timer to stop and then when you click the screen again the timer picks up where it left off and continues. Kind of like a toggle function.

I have the pause button toggling fine and the timer starts counting fine, but I don't know how to pause and play again between each click. How can I accomplish this?

I have a private boolean named "mVisible" because I tried to have the timer playing only when the "pause button" is invisible or (!mVisible) but I was only getting a null pointer exception.

Thank you!!

JAVA CODE:

```
package com.example.jonathan.om11;

import android.media.Image;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class Environment1Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private static final String TAG = "Environment1Activity";
    //Initiate for Timer
    protected int count = 0;
    private ImageView playerPause;
    private ImageView backgroundImageBtn;
    private boolean mVisible;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_environment1);
        hidePauseBtn();
        timer();

        AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);

        playerPause = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pauseBtn);
        playerPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                toggle();
            }
        });

        backgroundImageBtn = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.rainforest_img);
        backgroundImageBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                toggle();
            }
        });
    }

    private void toggle() {
        if (mVisible) {
            hide();

        } else {
            show();
        }
    }

    //Pause
    public void show() {
        playerPause = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pauseBtn);
        playerPause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mVisible = true;
        Log.d(TAG, "Player: PAUSED ");
    }


    //Play
    public void hide() {
        playerPause = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pauseBtn);
        playerPause.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mVisible = false;
    }

    //Hide pause button upon creating activity
    public void hidePauseBtn() {
        playerPause = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pauseBtn);
        playerPause.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }

    public void timer() {
        Timer timer = new Timer();

        //Count environment runtime
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        count++;
                        Log.d(TAG, "run: Time is " + count);
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 1000, 1000);
    }
}
```

XML CODE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.jonathan.om11.Environment1Activity">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/rainforest_img"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/rainforest_env" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/pauseBtn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/rainforest_img"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_pause_white_48dp" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

On your pause button click that is when you toggle ans show play button, stop the timer as well or remove it to stop the timer, then when play button is clicked, you re run a new instance of timer but it will update your counter from the previous value.
Make time variable class level when initializing it

Comment: thank you I will try to make these changes but I am still new to Android. 

I already have the toggle(); function placed for the "playerPause" instance, is that what you mean? Are you able to take the code I copied and give an example?